# How can I get the min XYZ values in 3ds max using pymxs?

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm writing a python script to get the southwestern vertex of the selected object, and get its coordinates X, Y and Z.

Logically the southwestern point would match the vertex having the minimum X, Y and Z. How can I access theses values in python?

So far I've been able to get the min XYZ values of the object, but it's resulting the bounding box values which is not the expected result. Instead I need the vertex values.

Can someone guide me through?

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt

aSelect = rt.selection[0]

minX = aSelect.min.x
minY = aSelect.min.y
minZ = aSelect.min.z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Southwestern' point is kinda open to interpretation (for example, I don't see the Z in the name), for the sake of argument let's pick the two most likely - one that gets the vertex that's furthest away from the object max, and one that get the vertex with the smallest total of x+y+x coords:

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt

obj = rt.selection[0]
mesh = rt.snapshotAsMesh(obj)

minDiagonalVert = max(list(mesh.verts), key=lambda vert: rt.distance(vert.pos, obj.max))
minTotalVert = min(list(mesh.verts), key=lambda vert: vert.pos.x + vert.pos.y + vert.pos.z)

rt.delete(mesh)
```

Quite obviously, this will work only for some kind of meshes, but that's up to you to set your own criteria that you want to match in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Swordslayer, it helped me to understand how to access the vertices informations.

Yes you're right 'southwestern' doesn't necessarily includes the Z, but implicitely I need the Z with the lowest value and this min Z should equal 0 for my purpose.

Anyway, now I was able to play around and it perfectly fit my needs, using these values to move the pivot position to this southwestern point of my object:

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt
from operator import itemgetter

anchor = rt.point3(0,0,0)
if len(rt.selection) == 0:
    print('no object selected! please select one object')
elif len(rt.selection) > 1:
    print('too much objects selected! please select one object')
else:
    aSelect = rt.selection[0]
    mesh = rt.convertToMesh (aSelect)
    vertices = list(mesh.verts)
    positions = []
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        positions.append(vertices[i].pos)
    positions = sorted(positions, key=itemgetter(2,1,0))
    minX = positions[0][0]
    minY = positions[0][1]
    minZ = positions[0][2]
    anchor = rt.point3(minX,minY,minZ)
    aSelect.pivot = anchor
    print('anchor set @ minX: {}, minY: {}, minZ: {}'.format(minX,minY,minZ))
```